# The evil, repressive government is trying to stop the heroes! For a very good reason, it turns out

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, trope

I have a memory of a short story in which a plucky group of scientists and researchers (and maybe students?) invent a machine that allows you to view any place and period in history.  It will revolutionize historical studies, but almost immediately the evil G-men of the oppressive government are after them, trying to seize and destroy their machine, muzzle the scientists, etc. etc.

Finally one of the G-Men catches the scrappy group of heroes.  And in a trope-breaking moment, we realize the evil government isn't really evil at all, but has realized what the scientists didn't - that being able to view any point of history anywhere on the planet will include "history" that happened just a second ago.  All privacy will be lost forever.

The scientists realize the implications of their discovery and agree to get rid of the device, but one ashen-faced scientist (or student) reveals that he had just mailed the plans for the device in the mail to a journalist, so they would be distributed to the world even if the scientists were caught.  The story ends with the G-man grimly welcoming the scientists to a new world of no privacy.

**UPDATED**: The story is "[The Dead Past](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v57n02_1956-04_Gorgon776)" (thank you, user14111!)

I can't think of any other stories that have explored this idea - the scrappy heroic underdogs fighting a faceless, repressive government... who turns out to have a very good reason for trying to suppress what the heroes are trying to do.  Are there any other stories that have explored this interesting twist on a common trope?

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Thanks, user14111 for the link.  Set it up as an answer and I'll accept it.  Not sure about the question being "too broad", though.  It's an unusual plot twist such that I can't think of any other stories like it - a government that looks like every other dystopian evil government... except that it's not.

Comment: @DavidWhite: "Too Broad" is our general flag for "we don't take suggestions questions".

Comment: Since the querent has indicated this is indeed "The Dead Past", I have marked it as a Duplicate. Amazingly enough, we seem to have only had this one answered and accepted once before...

Comment: @DavidWhite, Mack Reynolds, if I remember rightly, wrote a whole bunch of B-grade novels back in the 60s or so ending with the same twist.  There are probably other authors too.

Comment: While I can't suggest anything else investigating the theme of government trying to stop the heroes for a good reason, if you're interested in another story about a TV that can veiw the past try https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/823062.The_Light_of_Other_Days

Comment: Go to tvtropes, read Reasonable Authority Figure trope. Or Hero Antagonist and Villain Protagonist tropes.

Comment: better duplicate target at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243563/short-story-invention-of-a-device-to-view-the-past